# Trouble getting Grunt to run node.js script

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am a grunt and node noob but I managed to write a node script that does what I want it to and works from the command line.  I don't want to publish the script as a node module but I would like to run it from my grunt file.

What changes (if any) do I need to make to the script for this to work?

The more I read about configuring grunt files and custom tasks the more confused I get.  I currently have something that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        'mytaskname': 'what goes here?'
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('./node_modules/script_name');

    grunt.registerTask('run-from-command-line', 'description', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('Not running...');
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [grunt-execute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-execute) plugin for doing this which executes files in a node.js child process.

Example:
If your node script is in "node-scripts/script.js", Gruntfile.js would look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        execute: {
            target: {
                src: ["node-scripts/script.js"]
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-execute");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["execute"]);
};
```

Comment: I appreciate this.  I found a different way to do this by making a custom grunt task but I'll mark this as correct as it might help another noob in the future.